# reshape list of numpy arrays and then reshape back

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list which consists of several numpy arrays with different shapes.
I want to reshape this list of arrays into a numpy vector and then change each element in the vector and then reshape it back to the original list of arrays.

For example:

input

```
[numpy.zeros((2,2)), numpy.ones((3,3))]
```

- First

To vector

```
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

- Second

every time change only one element. for example change the 1st element 0 to 2

```
[0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

- Last

convert it back to

```
[array([[0,2],[0,0]]),array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])]
```

Is there any fast implementation? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like converting to a list and back will be inefficient.  Instead, why not figure out which array to index (and where) and then just update that index?  e.g.

```
def change_element(arr1, arr2, ix, value):
    which = ix >= arr1.size
    arr = [arr1, arr2][which]
    ix = ix - arr1.size if which else ix
    arr.ravel()[ix] = value
```

And here's some example usage:

```
>>> arr1 = np.zeros((2, 2))
>>> arr2 = np.ones((3, 3))
>>> change_element(arr1, arr2, 1, 2)
>>> change_element(arr1, arr2, 6, 3.14)
>>> arr1
array([[ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> arr2
array([[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  3.14],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]])
>>> change_element(arr1, arr2, 7, 3.14)
>>> arr1
array([[ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> arr2
array([[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  3.14],
       [ 3.14,  1.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]])
```

A few notes -- This updates the arrays in place.  It doesn't create new arrays.  If you really need to create new arrays, I suppose you could `np.copy` them and return.  Also, this relies on the arrays sharing memory before and after the `ravel`.  I don't remember the exact circumstances where `ravel` would return a new array rather than a view into the original array . . .

---

Generalizing to more arrays is actually quite easy.  We just need to walk down the list of arrays and see if `ix` is less than the array size.  If it is, we've found our array.  If it isn't, we need to subtract the array's size from `ix` to represent the number of elements we've traversed thus far:

```
def change_element(arrays, ix, value):
    for arr in arrays:
        if ix < arr.size:
            arr.ravel()[ix] = value
            return
        ix -= arr.size
```

And you can call this similar to before:

```
change_element([arr1, arr2], 6, 3.14159)
```

Comment: Nice. But this solution is limited to exactly two arrays. It would be interesting to generalize it to a list of arrays with an unspecified number of arrays.

Comment: @MikeMüller -- Sure.  Generalization is pretty easy though (easy enough that I added it as an addendum to the solution).

Comment: @mgilson Thank you very much. I think this solution could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@mgilson probably has the best answer for you, but if you absolutely have to convert to a flat list first and then go back again (perhaps because you need to do something else with the flat list as well), then you can do this with list comprehensions:

```
lst = [numpy.zeros((2,4)), numpy.ones((3,3))]
tlist = [e for a in lst for e in a.ravel()]
tlist[1] = 2
i = 0
lst2 = []
dims = [a.shape for a in lst]
for n, m in dims:
    lst2.append(np.array(tlist[i:i+n*m]).reshape(n,m))
    i += n*m
lst2

[array([[ 0.,  2.],
    [ 0.,  0.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])]
```

Of course, you lose the information about your array sizes when you flatten, so you need to store them somewhere (here, in `dims`).

Comment: This solution is quite elegant. Thank you.